# Navigate from a Custom UIViewController to a TabBarController without segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem when I navigate from a custom UIViewController to second tab of a TabBarController which of course is another UIViewController.
If I navigate from AdminPanel to Products is not crashing because I have a `push` from Products to AdminPanel. But from AdminPanel to Cart I don't have any `push`.

Here is a picture with the bug:

[image]

This is the error: " Could not cast value of type 'MyAppName.AdminPanelViewController' (0x10e878418) to 'MyAppName.ProductsViewController' (0x10e877e00). "

Here is my design:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    // PRODUCTS VC
    class ProductsViewController: UIViewController{

var selectedProductsArray = [Product]()
    var priceForSelectedProductsArray = [Float]()

       // Func which is using GestureRecognition to access the Admin Panel when we press on User Avatar
        func accessToAdminPanel(){

            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProductsViewController.adminImageTapped(gesture:)))

            userAvatarImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        }

        // Function to open the AdminPanelViewController
        @objc func adminImageTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.nameOfMainSB, bundle:nil)
            let adminPanelVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.adminPanelStoryboard) as! AdminPanelViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(adminPanelVC, animated: true)

        }


        // Func which will add the product into an array of products when the user press Add To Cart
        func didTapAddToCart(_ cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
            let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)

            addProduct(at: indexPath!)
            selectedProductsArray.append(productsArray[(indexPath?.row)!]) // Append products for cart
            priceForSelectedProductsArray.append(productsArray[(indexPath?.row)!].price) // Append prices for selected products
        }

    }


    // CART VC
    class CartViewController: UIViewController {

 var productsInCartArray = [Product]()
    var productPricesArray = [Float]()

     // Append the selectedProducts into productsInCartArray using the TabBarController
        func fetchSelectedProducts() {

    // ------------------HERE IS CRASHING AT THIS LINE -----------------------
            productsInCartArray = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).selectedProductsArray
            productPricesArray = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProductsViewController).priceForSelectedProductsArray
            totalSum = productPricesArray.reduce(0, +)
        }

    }
```

If you can't figure out with this section of code where is crashing I can give you the link to git source code because I don't have anything to hide.

Thank you so much for your time if you are reading this and I hope you can help me because for half day I try to find a solution to fix this bug which crash my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

topViewController now is admin not products so you need to get the VC at index 0 which is products

```
productsInCartArray = ((self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! ProductsViewController).selectedProductsArray
```

Comment: Where to add that line of code ? I need a function in AdminPanel ?

Comment: your current code doesn't contain where the crash points , please attach the code where you cast to **as! ProductsViewController**

Comment: But is there in my post. I also added a comment with "HERE IS CRASHING"

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're trying to force a `AdminPanelViewController` to a `ProductsViewController` (in the `topViewController as! ProductsViewController` part of that line.) This is because when you push to the AdminPanelViewController it gets moved to the top of the navigation stack, replacing the ProductsViewController that you are assuming is supposed to be there.

There are a number of ways to deal with this error in the short term, such as iterating through the navigation stack instead of just grabbing the topViewController, like this:

```
guard let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController else {
    // handle error
    return
}
for controller in navController.viewControllers {
    if let productsController = controller as? ProductsViewController {
        // do work here
    }
}
```

But I think more fundamentally you'll have to re-think how you're accessing things. In general, you shouldn't be walking the navigation stack to do work. You're better off passing data between controllers as you navigate the stack.

Also, you should try to avoid force casts with `as!` and should use `as?` instead, which will allow you to catch cases where the casting doesn't work without the app crashing. My personal goal is to only use `!` in IBOutlet declarations and nowhere else, but your mileage may vary.